# Is the Maxmind database included in the composer install?

Tags: php, geolocation, maxmind

This is probably pretty obvious. I ran through the maxmind documentation to install geoip via Composer.

It is installed now and the directories are created. when trying to add the script to my php file I get the following error:

```
   Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The file "/usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIP2-City.mmdb" does not exist or is not readable.' in /home/mysite/mysite.com/vendor/maxmind-db/reader/src/MaxMind/Db/Reader.php:48 Stack trace: #0 /home/mysite/mysite.com/vendor/geoip2/geoip2/src/Database/Reader.php(53): MaxMind\Db\Reader->__construct('/usr/local/shar...') #1 /home/mysite/mysite.com/shopping_carttest.php(26): GeoIp2\Database\Reader->__construct('/usr/local/shar...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/mysite/mysite.com/vendor/maxmind-db/reader/src/MaxMind/Db/Reader.php on line 48
```

This is the code in the php file:

```
/maxmind geoip
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;

// This creates the Reader object, which should be reused across
// lookups.
$reader = new Reader('/usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIP2-City.mmdb');

// Replace "city" with the appropriate method for your database, e.g.,
// "country".
$record = $reader->country('128.101.101.101');
```

Obviously the file location is not finding that database file. During the install procedure I am not sure if that database file was added anywhere. I am not sure if the file was added during the composer install or if I need to manually add it? And if it was added during the composer install where it was created.

Comment: Check your vendor folder in GeoIP there will be a file

Comment: @SaadSuri I went through the 3 folders that were created in the vendor folder: geoip2, maxmind, maxmind-db and all the sub folders, none of them had any mmdb files in them. I ended up downloading the database file from the maxmind site and changing the url the reader is pulling the db in from. I'm not sure if that is the correct way to do this because the database will then not be automatically updated but im not sure what else to do.

Comment: Yes the data file is not included in the composer bundle. You will need to automate the update via PHP or the Maxmind update script: https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoipupdate/